# Paired data with independent groups of treatment, how to plan and analyze?

Tags: measurement-error, paired-data, equivalence

I need your assistance, I am trying to design an experiment, and in order to do so I need to know how the data will be analyzed.

The experiment in on rats. Each rat gets some treatment, and a measure is being taken before and after the treatment. In other words, for each rat I will have the difference D.

The measurements are angels, for example: Before = 100 degrees, and after = 80 degrees.
The problem with this measure - the measurement error can be up to 10 degrees (+- 10).

Now I have 4 groups of different treatments, I have 1 control and 3 experimental treatments. My aim is to check if any of the experimental treatments is better than the control. I am less interested in finding out if there is a difference between the experimental treatments.

And for the biggest problem: Smaller values of D are better...if a treatment works, I expect the values AFTER to be as close as possible to the values BEFORE.

How should I analyze such a data ? If I'll know that, maybe I can figure out how to dig a sample size...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can I simply calculate the difference D for each rat, and then run a one way ANOVA to compare the means ? Will it be valid ?